# Как перезаписать переменную содержащую ссылку (очистить от лишних символов)

Tags: php

Есть переменная, в которую попадают значения (адреса сайтов).
Как очистить знание переменной от лишних символов (http://), если они там были, а также вывести сообщение "ссылка содержала http://"

```
$link = "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
```

Comment: Сами пробовали?

Comment: пробовал искать, за полчаса не разобрался. Так как совершенно пока не знаю регулярных выражений. А времени мало остается, понятно тчо за день разобрался бы

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, проверку можно сделать и без регулярных выражений, с помощью [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php). Поставил минус за абсолютное нежелание разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Вы всё ещё кипятите? Тогда мы идём к вам: для работы с url (валидация, парсинг) существуют штатные функции в языке. А вы то регулярками, то str_replace... И никто не показал топикстартеру рукой в направлении filter_var, parse_url...

Comment: @AK мне даже интересно какое бы вы извращение написали с помощью `parse_url` для очистки значения от некоторых лишних символов и еще и вывести сообщение о содержании этих лишних символов. про `filter_var` вообще молчу. Не сдерживайте себя - напишите ответ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Даже  и не собираюсь. Я собираюсь намекнуть топикстартеру, что его задача -- явно велосипедно-костыльная и её можно слегка перефразировать так, чтобы можно было пользоваться нормальным тестированием входных переменных (урл/не урл) и вообще поинтересоваться, зачем вообще от ссылки отшибать протокол.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оптимальный вариант решения задачи

```
$cnt = 0;
$link = str_replace("http://","",$link,$cnt);
if($cnt) {
  echo "была замена";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php читайте доки. и не надо кастылей с регулярками которые в сотню раз тяжелее чем просто взять число замен из `str_replace`

п.c. Дополню ответ для очистки url используем

```
$urlNew = filter_var($url,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

if(strlen($urlNew) != strlen($url)) {
   echo "Была замена";
}
```

Comment: Думаю ТС только в вопросе указал конкретно `http://`. Мне кажется в итоге потом будут именно набор различных символов, которые будут искаться и выводиться именно что "символы x y 1123 были в строке, извините сэээр" ... а тогда для этого точно нужны будут регулярки. Но это как мне кажется)

Answer (score 2):

Ну например так:

```
if (preg_match('/^http\:\/\//', $link, $matches))
{
    $link = str_replace($matches[1], '', $link);
    echo 'Ссылка содержала http://';
}
```

(какой вопрос - такой ответ :)

Comment: то, что надо)))

Comment: Сравнить регулярной а потом делать. П.с. условие вообще лишнее

Comment: @Naumov условие не лишнее. топикстартер хотел вывести сообщение если была замена.

Comment: Та всё равно минус для проверки стоит использовать `strpos` но ни как не регулярку.

Comment: в частном случае - да, но вопрос был слишком общий "найти символы". я понял, что "например http:// но может и что-то еще".

Comment: регулярка не выход в любом случае, к примеру как в моём ответе лучше просто  взять число сколько замен  было при применение `str_replace` если больше 0 замена была если 0 то небыло... и лишние проверки не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

Профит (вроде-бы должно работать) :

```
$link = str_replace("http://","",$link);
```